# Need to call data from insecure URL for GCM push notification for chrome

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, chrome-gcm

I need to call an insecure (http://) URL to fetch data form service worker file for GCM push notification for chrome. Is this possible anyway?

Comment: The third point in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871787/how-to-register-a-service-worker-from-different-sub-domain addresses your question.

Answer (score 1):

I did a long search and as @Jeff Posnick written in my another question's([how to register a service worker from different sub domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871787/how-to-register-a-service-worker-from-different-sub-domain)) answer. It seems for security reason it's not allowed by GCM team to call a insecure service in service worker or while working on GCM push notification for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Not to reboot this thread, but I stumbled upon this as well. Two solutions are creating a github repository (where you have a standard ssl-certificate) or getting a free certificate from startssl. For the last one, you might need permissions that are not standard in your hosting package.