# how to register a service worker from different sub domain

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have two subdomains: https://abc.xxxx.com and https://xyz.xxxx.com. So my questions:

> 1). is it possible to register a service worker for
>   https://xyz.xxxx.com from https://abc.xxxx.com  ? if yes then how?
>
> 2). if http://abc.xxxx.com (**http** insecure) then anyway to register
>   a service worker for https://xyz.xxxx.com from http://abc.xxxx.com like in iframe or something....

This is a real situation, I am facing for my multiple subdomain. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any relation with jQuery ?

Comment: not directly, i thought might help in case opening widow like ifame or something....anyway removed it.

Comment: are you able to fix it?. i have similar issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190711/using-service-workers-across-multiple-subdomains

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here are some general answers that I think should address the various points you raise in your question:

- Each registered service worker has an associated [`scope`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#service-worker-registration-scope), which dictates the set of web pages that the service worker can control. The `scope` of a service worker is a URL, and that URL must have the same origin as the page that registers the service worker, and must be either a URL that corresponds to the same path level as the page or a path that's one or more levels down. The default `scope` corresponds to the same path level as location of the service worker script. Because of this restriction, it's not possible to call `navigator.serviceWorker.register(...)` from a page on one (sub-)domain and end up with a service worker that controls pages on another (sub-)domain.
- There are restrictions in place to prevent you from throwing an `https:` `<iframe>` on an `http:` page and using that to register a service worker. See [DOMException when registering service worker inside an https iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702247/domexception-when-registering-service-worker-inside-an-https-iframe)
- Though I don't know that it's directly related to your question, explicitly calling `fetch()` for an `http:` resource within your service worker code will result in a failure in current versions of Chrome, since mixed-content `fetch()`s are not allowed within a service worker. I don't know if things are 100% settled on that front, and [this open bug](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/493) is still relevant.

If you have pages that live on both `abc.123.com` and `xyz.123.com` and you want both sets of pages to be controlled by a service worker, then you need to have two separate service worker registrations. Each registration needs to be for a copy of your service worker JS file that's hosted on the respective domain corresponding to the top-level page, and all pages and service worker scripts need to be accessed via `https:`.

That being said, you **can** kick off a service worker registration for a different domain by including a cross-domain `<iframe>` on a page, but both the host page and the `<iframe>` need to be served via `https:`. The normal service worker scoping restrictions apply, so if, for example, you want to register a service worker for the other domain that will cover the entire `https://other-domain.com/` scope, you need to make sure that the location of the service worker script being registered is at the top-level, e.g. `https://other-domain.com/service-worker.js`, not at `https://other-domain.com/path/to/service-worker.js`. This is the approach used by, for example, the [AMP project](https://www.ampproject.org/) via the  [`<amp-install-serviceworker>` element](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-install-serviceworker/amp-install-serviceworker.md).

Comment: Correct. The answer to both is no.

Comment: Alright, let me do some more search if found same then i'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for help

Comment: FWIW, my original explanation had a few technical errors. I've since cleaned it up.

Comment: @JeffPosnick: does the "no" still apply when one subdomain is absent entirely? That is, if there's a service worker for `example.com`, does it have no effect on `subdomain.example.com`?

Comment: A SW on example.com can't control anything on subdomain.example.com. The two origins would be different in that scenario, and there's no concept of a "superset" origin.

Answer (score 6):

`Service Worker scripts must be hosted at the same origin (Protocol + Domain name + Port).` Each sub-domain is considered a different origin, So, you will need to register a service worker for each one. Each of these workers will have its own `cache` and `scope`.

Comment: how do i make this work if only the port is different ? (on localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Try use Ngnix proxy_pass. This work for me.

Answer (score -2):

My bad, I misunderstood a bit. Well, here's the code

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    if(window.location.pathname != '/'){
        //register with API
        if(!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker', { scope: '/' });
        //once registration is complete
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration){
            //get subscription
            serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(subscription){

                //enable the user to alter the subscription
                //jquery selector for enabling whatever you use to subscribe.removeAttr("disabled");
                //set it to allready subscribed if it is so
                if(subscription){
                    //code for showing the user that they're allready subscribed
                }
            });
        });
    }   
}else{  
    console.warn('Service workers aren\'t supported in this browser.');  
}
```

then here's the event -ish for your subscribe / unsubscribe

```
// subscribe or unsubscribe to the ServiceWorker
$(document.body).on('change', /*selector*/, function(){
    //new state is checked so we subscribe
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration){
            serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()  
                .then(function(subscription){  
                    // The subscription was successful  
                    console.log('subscription successful'); //subscription.subscriptionId

                    //save in DB - this is important because 
                    $.post($('#basePath').val() + 'settings/ajax-SW-sub/', {id:subscription.subscriptionId}, function(data){
                        //console.log(data);
                    }, 'json');

                    }).catch(function(e) {  
                        if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {  
                            // The user denied the notification permission which  
                            // means we failed to subscribe and the user will need  
                            // to manually change the notification permission to  
                            // subscribe to push messages
                            console.warn('Permission for Notifications was denied');
                        } else {  
                            // A problem occurred with the subscription; common reasons  
                            // include network errors, and lacking gcm_sender_id and/or  
                            // gcm_user_visible_only in the manifest.  
                            console.error('Unable to subscribe to push.', e);
                        }  
                    });  
        });//*/
    //new state us unchecked so we unsubscribe
    }else{
        $('.js-enable-sub-test').parent().removeClass('checked');
        //get subscription
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
            reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(subscription) {
                //unregister in db
                $.post($('#basePath').val() + 'settings/ajax-SW-unsub/', {id:subscription.subscriptionId}, function(data){
                    //console.log(data);
                }, 'json');

                //remove subscription from google servers
                subscription.unsubscribe().then(function(successful) {
                    // You've successfully unsubscribed
                    console.log('unsubscribe successful');
                }).catch(function(e) {
                    // Unsubscription failed
                    console.log('unsubscribe failed', e);
                })
            })        
        });//*/
    }
});
```

after that you need to register an account on the google developer console and register a project for something like *.xxxx.com . Then you need to get a proper manifest json with gcm_sender_id and gcm_user_visible_only

You need to create a key for both server and browser applications, there's more info on that on this page.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en

The one for browser applications goes in your manifest json.

Then to send out push notifications you'll be using something like this:

```
  function addSWmessage($args){

    $output = false;

    if(!isset($args['expiration']) || $args['expiration'] == ''){
        $args['expiration'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+7 days', time()));
    }

    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `serviceworker_messages` SET title = '%s', body = '%s', imageurl = '%s', linkurl = '%s', hash = '%s', expiration = '%s'",
                    parent::escape_string($args['title']),
                    parent::escape_string($args['text']),
                    parent::escape_string($args['imageurl']),
                    parent::escape_string($args['linkurl']),
                    parent::escape_string(md5(uniqid('******************', true))),
                    parent::escape_string($args['expiration']));

    if($id = parent::insert($sql)){
        $output = $id;
    }

    return $output;

}
function pushSWmessage($args){

    //$args['messageid'] $args['userids'][]

    foreach($args['userids'] as $val){

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT messages_mobile, messages FROM `users_serviceworker_hash` WHERE users_id = '%s'",
                        parent::escape_string($val));

        if($row = parent::queryOne($sql)){
            $m1 = json_decode($row['messages'], true);
            $m1[] = $args['messageid'];
            $m2 = json_decode($row['messages_mobile'], true);
            $m2[] = $args['messageid'];

            $sql = sprintf("UPDATE `users_serviceworker_hash` SET messages = '%s', messages_mobile = '%s' WHERE users_id = '%s'",
                            parent::escape_string(json_encode($m1)),
                            parent::escape_string(json_encode($m2)),
                            parent::escape_string($val['users_id']));

            parent::insert($sql);
        }
    }

    $sql = sprintf("SELECT subscriptionID, users_id FROM `users_serviceworker_subscriptions`");

    if($rows = parent::query($sql)){

        foreach($rows as $val){
            if(in_array($val['users_id'], $args['userids'])){
                $registrationIds[] = $val['subscriptionID'];
            }
        }
        if(isset($registrationIds) && !empty($registrationIds)){
            // prep the bundle
            $msg = array
            (
                'message'       => '!',
                'title'         => '!',
                'subtitle'      => '!',
                'tickerText'    => '!',
                'vibrate'       => 1,
                'sound'         => 1,
                'largeIcon'     => '!',
                'smallIcon'     => '!'
            );

            $headers = array
            (
                'Authorization: key='.SW_API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

            $fields = array
            (
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
                'data'              => $msg
            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
    }

}
```

And no, I don't know what issue you've been having but this works for me with multiple sub domains. :)

Comment: thank for answer BUT I think you miss understand my question sorry for if mean of my question goes wrong. 
my question is related to registration of service worker, not intercepting request in promise(fetch).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!! But my question is very specific for registration a service worker which code exist on other sub domain....