# Using service workers across multiple subdomains

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

If my web app consists of more than one subdomain, does that mean I have to have multiple service workers, one for each subdomain? Or can I have one service worker that works across subdomains?

Comment: It'd be useful to know more details about the structure of your app. See @mkhatib's answer for two different meanings of a "web app [that] consists of more than one subdomain," and how the answers vary by meaning.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each subdomain is considered a different origin, so yes, you will need to register a service worker for each one. Each of these workers will have its own cache and scope.

Answer (score 6):

Each subdomain is considered a different origin and you must register a service worker for each origin but you can reuse the same source for the service worker by setting the [`Service-Worker-Allowed`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-allowed) response header to the list of scopes the same source can control.

Comment: That link isn't working properly, see https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-allowed instead.

Comment: Also, to clarify, the header should be included in the response for the service worker itself (e.g. `sw.js`) as described in: https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-script-response

Answer (score 6):

If you mean by multiple domains is that the user can access your site directly on multiple domains like `www.example.com` and `hello.example.com` then I believe the answer is yes, you need multiple service workers to handle each.

However, if your main app is served on one domain `www.example.com` but might call other domains like `api.example.com` or `images.examples.com` or even `fonts.gstatic.com` to load Google Fonts or `example.s3.amazonaws.com`  to load static assets then a single service worker is enough. This is how you can catch and cache (or do whatever you'd like to the requests):

```
(function() {
  var DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL = 'images/default-avatar@200x150.png';

  function profileImageRequest(request) {
    // Load from cacheOnly to avoid redownloading the images since if the user
    // updates their avatar its URL will change.
    return toolbox.cacheOnly(request).catch(function() {
      return toolbox.networkFirst(request).catch(function() {
        return toolbox.cacheOnly(new Request(DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL));
      });
    });
  }

  toolbox.precache([DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL]);
  toolbox.router.get('/(.+)/users/avatars/(.*)', profileImageRequest, {
    origin: /example\.s3\.amazonaws\.com/
  });
})();
```

In the example I am using [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) library from Chrome team to help you cache different assets.