# How service worker works with sub-domain?

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

i am using Angular 6 and ngsw-config.json for service worker configuration but i dont have a clue about how it works with sub-domains.

from my understanding

1. user lands in **example.com** .
2. service worker gets registered for **example.com**.
3. what happens to **abc.example.com** , **xyz.example.com** ?

**what should be done to cache assetsGroups and dataGroups of all sub-domains ?**

here is my current ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  },{
    "name": "fonts",
    "resources": {
      "urls": [
        "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
        "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "database",
      "urls": [
        "https://**.api.example.com/pl/**",
        "https://**.api.example.com/en/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 100000000,
        "maxAge": "3d",
        "timeout": "2m"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35190712/5995040),"each subdomain is considered a different origin, so yes, you will need to register a service worker for each one. Each of these workers will have its own cache and scope." Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Service worker treats each domain and sub-domain as a unique app and of different origin. So separate service worker is required for each sub-domain that you are going to use. [Here is a nice article](https://medium.com/@drenzulli/building-progressive-web-apps-on-multi-subdomain-sites-fbd3384d0706) which discusses various options you have.

If you think you can have sub-domains mapped to single domain as well with alias(say abc.example.com to example.com/abc/), you can just manage your app with one service worker.

But when that's not an option, having multiple service workers and pre-cache when appropriate would be the ideal alternate.