# PWAs on subdomain - installing together

Tags: javascript, android, angular, progressive-web-apps

One of PWA applications (app A) has link to another app (app B).

I put them on one subdomain together (as in the example: https://nebula-cross.glitch.me/) and everything is fine - when I installing app A, app B is installed too. The problem is, when I want to put the applications on subdomains. Now, when I install app A, app B is not installed. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, example is here: https://available-channel.glitch.me/ i want to install "available-channel" with "nebula-cross" app (in one installation).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible because the navigation is restricted to the scope of a manifest.

So the same behavior will occur when you access this subdomain from your App #1 to App #2.

Source: https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#navigation-scope

Related discussion: [Using service workers across multiple subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190711/using-service-workers-across-multiple-subdomains)