# Can a browser check to see if it has a JS library regardless of its source and use it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, single-page-application

**BLUF**

Can a browser be told to check to see if it already has a JS library cached from another source by using some sort of identifying metric (Hash, Signature, Version ID, etc) and then use the cached version instead of re-downloading it?

**Problem**

Assume that there a hundreds of devices on an offline network that have slightly different Single Page Apps (SPA) that all use the same single large JS library. They each serve both the SPA and library locally. Admins of these devices will have fast access to some devices and slow access to others. I am trying to determine if there is anyway to speed up the downloading of the SPA to the Admin's browser for the 'slow access' devices by leveraging the common use of the large library.

The ideal solution would be opportunistic. It would ask the browser if it has the large JS Library with a certain has hash (`liblarge.js`,`sha-256: B4...X`) and if it did use it, if not then load the one over the slow link.

I understand that I could try to determine the fast access devices and then try to serve the large library from them, but this would require some sort of reconnaissance along with overhead.

I also understand that I could try to put something like a CDN on the network and serve the large JS lib but there are other aspects of the offline network that make this difficult.

Comment: Do you control the source code of the SPAs?

Comment: The way web workers are set up in Create-React-App can give you an idea of how to cache a js file.

Comment: A CDN is what you want. Once those files are cached, that part could work offline...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, I do.

Comment: @Cerbrus - not an option, don't control the network

Comment: @TKoL - Is the the basic mechanism you were referencing? https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Comment: @LiamKelly I think so.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what do you mean by "BLUFF" in your question? That's not a use of the word "bluff" I've come across in my 50 some-odd years of speaking English... :-)

Comment: Typo, meant to be BLUF - 'Bottom Line Up Front'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you control the source code

Update them all to use a single URL for the library+version combination, which is on a fast device, regardless of which device that specific SPA is on. Ensure that the library+version combination is served with far-future caching headers. (Updating the library+version will require changing its path/name, to defeat the caching headers.)

### If you don't control the source code

No, there's no API to the browser that lets you do this, not least because querying what libraries pages/apps from other origins use would be a security hazard.

Comment: concerning case 2, `regardless of the URL` comment: can any URL be associated with a single origin?

Comment: @LiamKelly - I'm not quite sure what you're asking there...?

Comment: You said a service worker could cache the large library `regardless of the URL` but then add `they have to be within the same origin`. It is my understanding that the Origin is the host portion of the URL. If this is correct, then the service work does not buy me anything. If it is not, and I can make the devices say they are all part of the same origin, then I might be able to make something work.

Comment: If you're asking whether any files cached with service worker will be "scoped" to the domain that the service worker is running on, and not accessible outside of it, yes.

Comment: @LiamKelly - Yeah, the service worker approach won't work. I was thinking subdomains and `document.origin`, but...[no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190711/using-service-workers-across-multiple-subdomains). :-)