# PWA fullscreen on iOS

Tags: android, ios, fullscreen, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app that is added to Home Screen as a bookmark. The first page is in full screen mode as below.

[image]

When I click into an icon (URL with different subdomain), the page opens with the bar in red below.

[image]

How could we make sure this bar doesn't show?

My code in both pages is:

```
 <!-- Manifest for android -->
<link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">
<!-- Hide browser URL bar for Android devices -->
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<!-- Hide browser URL bar for iOS devices -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Manifest:

```
{
      "short_name": "XXXX",
      "name": "XXXX",
      "icons": [
        {
          "src": "/launcher-icon-1x.png",
          "type": "image/png",
          "sizes": "120x120"
        },
        {
          "src": "/launcher-icon-2x.png",
          "type": "image/png",
          "sizes": "144x144"
        }
      ],
      "start_url": "/",
      "scope": "./",
      "background_color": "#0FA4D9",
      "display": "fullscreen",
      "theme_color": "#0FA4D9"
    }
```

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190711/using-service-workers-across-multiple-subdomains

Comment: This is normal behavior. Your external subdomain is a different subdomain. So the browser treats it as if it is an external site. So it opens it in the browser, just like it would from a native app.

To keep them within your PWA you have to serve the content from the same origin. It can be a sub folder, etc.