# Service worker remote/foreign installation

Tags: service-worker

Say I have a subdomain `app.my-main-site.com`. This subdomain has a service worker `app.my-main-site.com/sw.js` that installs properly when you navigate to `app.my-main-site.com` to allow offline use.

Is it possible to start the service worker installation process from the root domain -- `my-main-site.com`? This would enable someone to immediately go offline after visiting `my-main-site.com`, but still be able to access `app.my-main-site.com` later while still offline.

For the sake of a practical example, the root domain `my-main-site.com` also has a service worker `my-main-site.com/sw.js` for making itself offline-enabled.

Essentially, is it possible to do something like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://app.my-main-site.com/sw.js', {
  scope: 'https://app.my-main-site.com'
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: The last paragraph of http://stackoverflow.com/a/31883194/385997 has some info about using <iframe>s to do this.

Comment: @JeffPosnick Thank you for your help. I completely glossed over the possibility of using an iframe!