# Can a service worker be made to ignore subfolders?

Tags: javascript, scope, service-worker

I have a service worker running on mydomain.com with the default scope of /

I don't want the service worker to run on mydomain.com/phpmyadmin

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What actions does `ServiceWorker` perform?

Comment: When you registry the service worker you can specify the scope, but in that case you will need something like: mydomain.com/validScope. and your **sw** will be available only on that scope.

Comment: @guest271314 The serviceworker is used for push notifications using google firebase.

Comment: @Hosar I'm assuming that means it's not possible at the moment unless I put the main site under a subfolder?

Comment: @user2145184 Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question? What is the issue you are currently having?

Comment: Do not `ServiceWorker` require registration for each subdomain currently?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871787/how-to-register-a-service-worker-from-different-sub-domain